# Are the values returned by numpy.empty() random or not?

Tags: python, numpy

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

reads that "Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries."
Q1:what do "without initializing entries." mean here.
Q2:Are the output returned by np.empty() are random numbers? 
I am using below code to generate an array and I am getting same output so how could they be random numbers?

import numpy as np

print(np.empty([2,2]))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run np.empty for the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948541/run-np-empty-for-the-second-time)

Answer (score 8):

The array is allocated in memory but each item in the area is uninitialized just like an uninitialized variable. In other words, the items in the array have not had their values set and are just taking the value that was held in memory until you explicitly assign them a value. Sometimes this value is 0 or close to it, but there is no guarantee what was in memory at those locations.  Here is the note on the [reference page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html):

> empty, unlike zeros, does not set the array values to zero, and may therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used with caution.

So unless you have a certain use case, go with `zeros` or something else. I'll also note that typically Python does not allow you to just declare a variable without initializing it, which is why this behavior might seem strange.